# Wordpress widget shows up as option, but does not display

Tags: php, wordpress

Following along with a course at lynda, I've done this, slightly modified from their basic example. It shows up in my Wordpress admin, and I can drag it into my sidebar widgets. What it should do, is insert a Bee Gees lyric into my sidebar (basic hello word thing, in other words), but no such lyrics are in the sidebar, regardless of where I place the widget.

Code is all in discowidget.php in my wordpress plugins dir, and as I said, it is present in the admin. here is the code:

```
<?php
/*
    Plugin Name: Disco Widget
    Plugin URI: gopher://disco/
    Description: This is not just a plugin, it symbolizes the hope and enthusiasm of an entire generation summed up in modernist lyrics sung most famously by the Bee Gees: Disco. When activated you will randomly see a lyric from the disco era.
    Author: Disco Stu
    Version: Jesus
    Author URI: http://tenprinthello.ca/
 */

 class DiscoWidget extends WP_Widget 
 {
     function DiscoWidget ()
    {

    }

    function widget($args, $instance)
    {
        exract( $args, EXTR_SKIP );
        $title = ( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : 'The Disco Widget';
        $body = ( $instance['body'] ) ? $instance['body'] : 'Well, you can tell by the way I use my walk.';
        ?>
        <?php echo $before_widget; ?>
        <?php echo $before_title . $title . $after_title ?>
        <p><?php echo $body ?></p>
        <?php 
    }

    function update()
    {

    }

    function form()
    {

    }
 }

 function disco_widget_init()
 {
     register_widget("DiscoWidget");
 }
 add_action('widgets_init','disco_widget_init');

?>
```

Comment: Do you have the sidebar displaying correctly in the theme?  Do other widgets work?  Also, is there a reason you are extracting $args instead of just using $args?

Comment: I only sort of know what I'm doing here; as I said, I'm following along with a video - http://www.lynda.com/WordPress-tutorials/Writing-constructor-registering-widgets/68626/76299-4.html (it's behind a paywall). Their code is essentially the same, except different name and different text in the variables.

Yes, other widgets in the sidebar do work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would recommend using a constructor function and removing the function named DiscoWidget():

```
//function DiscoWidget(){}

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct('DiscoWidget', 'DiscoWidget', array( 'description' => 'DiscoWidget')    );
}
```

Also, echo your closing $after_widget:

```
<?php echo $after_widget; ?>
```